# is there a method that allows to determine if NOUN is a person or Object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have a text in input like :

```
the economist made a report to summarize what was done.
```

and i want to get in output :

```
economist : NOUN/Person
report : NOUN/object
```

So, i want to determine from a NOUN if it is a person or object (like semantic classification)

Comment: What is the code that fails for you here?

Comment: I want to have some idea, how we can do this , i am beginner and i want to have this output from the given text as an example

Comment: You added `nltk` and `spacy` tags, so try those libraries.

Comment: I recommend having a look at Wordnet. Once you have some code and if you're still having problems, please post it here and we can help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think Named Entity Recognition is what you are looking for. Take a look at the NLTK doc: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

Comment: NER will not solve this problem. Economist, for example, is not a named entity.

Comment: exactly!  Economist is not a named entity